# Coordinates of the lasso estimator

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, high-dimensional

The lasso estimator is
$$
\hat\beta = \underset{\beta}{\text{argmin}}||Y-X\beta||_2^2+r||\beta||_1
$$
I always read that the coordinates $\hat\beta_j$ of the lasso estimator tend to be either clearly separated from zero or zero exactly. But when I check the outputs of glmnet or other algorithms, I regularly find values that are very small but not exactly zero:  $\hat\beta_j=0.0000018$ for example. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please give a reproducible example, that is, code that we can copy verbatim into R? That would help us know the issue you’re facing. My suspicion is that you’re getting values around $10^{-16}$, which is basically zero in R, but I’d like to see an example and not just guess.

Comment: It's very much possible to get small but nonzero coefficient estimates in lasso. Indeed, if you slowly vary the regularization parameter, you will see that the parameter estimates smoothly move between the OLS estimated value and zero (and so reach arbitrarily small yet nonzero values along the way).

Comment: @JohnMadden I think they vary continuously rather than smoothly (there are slight kinks when new coefficients are introduced, as illustrated at https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html ).  This does not affect your point

Comment: @Henry you right; the path is piecewise linear with a Gaussian likelihood as in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should write
$$
\widehat{\beta}\in\text{argmin}_{\beta}||Y-X\beta||_2^2+r||\beta||_1,
$$
because the lasso estimator is not necessarily unique.

Second, you can get intuition about why the coordinates of the lasso estimator tend to be exactly equal to zero by considering orthogonal design ($X^T X=\sqrt{n}I$, where $n$ is the number of samples and $I$ the identity matrix):
the lasso estimator is then the soft-thresholding operator:
$$
\hat{\beta}_j=\text{sign}[X^TY](|X^TY|-r/2)_+/n,
$$
where $(|X^TY|-r/2)_+:=|X^TY|-r/2$ if $|X^TY|>r/2$ and $(|X^TY|-r/2)_+=:0$ otherwise,
see Exercise 2.10 in ["Fundamentals of High-Dimensional Statistics: With Exercises and R Labs"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-73792-4) for more details.
Hence, the coordinates of the lasso for orthogonal design are exactly zero if and only if $|X^TY|\leq r/2$.

Finally, the reason why algorithms still yield very small values on a regular basis is not that $|X^TY|$ is almost equal to $r/2$ (this can happen but only with very small probability) but that the algorithms only *approximate* the lasso solution (by coordinate descent in the case of glmnet). In other words, what you see is a numerical phenomenon.